# Binding an inputText value to a viewScope with a computed name

Tags: data-binding, xpages

I have an inputText component on a custom control and I am trying to bind the value to a viewScope, but the viewScope name is computed using a compositeData value and string.

If I hardcode the value binding it works, for example:
    value="${viewScope['BillingDate_From']}"

The viewScope name is computed using the following javascript code:
    compositeData.dateRangeFilter[0].from_fieldname + '_From'

I have tried many ways of achieving this but with no success, sometimes it errors, usually unexpected character errors but most of the time the inputText box is empty.

The code I have most recently tried:
    value="${viewScope[#{javascript:compositeData.dateRangeFilter[0].from_fieldname + '_From'}]}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found, and I don't know the reason for this, that trying to bind dynamically doesn't work if there's any string concatenation in the evaluation. The way I got around this was by creating a custom control that accepts a bindingValue and dataSource as parameters, then passing in the document and field name I want to use. For whatever reason, if the code uses composite data, it still allows for editing when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I thought it was either me not considering all options or a limitation. I have now added the viewScope name as a required property definition, not best, but definitely works

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this to build what you need:

The Control:

```
           <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.scopeName+"}";}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:inputText>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.scopeName+"}";}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

The XPage using the Control:

```
<xc:cc id="xx">
    <xc:this.scopeName><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "viewScope." + " calculatedScopeVarName";}]]></xc:this.scopeName>
    </xc:cc>
    <xp:button value="Beschriftung" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="xx">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Instead of "viewScope" you cant add session or another scope and instead of calculatedScopeVar you can enter the name of your var. But this has a limit, it only works if the calculatedScopeVar is accesable through the component onLoad. For example it will not work if you use this control in a Repeat control and try to use the repeated array as calculatedScopeVar.

Comment: Michael, are you sure? I have this type of implementation working in a repeat control using a view as my data source, getting values from the view entry for the passed-in value for the field.